# Upgraded to WebAPI2 and DotNetNuke 7.2.1 and all services returning 404.0

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, dotnetnuke-7

I wrote some WebAPI controllers using WebAPI for DotNetNuke 7.0 using this [method](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community-blog/cid/142400/Getting-Started-with-Services-Framework-WebAPI-Edition)

Everything worked great.

Today I upgraded DNN to 7.2.1 and upgraded my projects to ASP.NET Web API2 and my services on my local machine are now not working - they return "HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found".

I think it is something to do with IIS and extensionless URLs - I checked IIS and DesktopModules is not an application as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19203815/adding-services-framework-web-api-to-dnn7-module).

I tried Fiddler and F12 Debugging tools and the message is giving no clues away. How can I debug this to work out where the problem lies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The folder that the webapi module is coming from supposed to be not an application, meaning it suppose to use the main web.config.
2. Check the web.config (file diff), what's got changed between the upgrades.

Comment: Thanks - Point 2 was the issue - I was missing a whole lot of Assembly BindingRedirects:        <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30AD4FE6B2A6AEED" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.1.0.0" newVersion="5.1.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
....

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  GET requests work fine, but I am still getting a 404 on POST.  :(

Comment: What version of DNN are you using Will? I am using the latest released DNN and I manually upgraded Newtonsoft (so after every DNN upgrade I have to overwrite about 6 dlls) - it is painful but my services work... messenging on DNN does not though (looks like it might work in DNN 8)